# how to gsap about continuity play

Tags: javascript, timeline, gsap, easing

I wanna work play method for continuity.
but I can't work only once.

If I use restart method, I can continuous action.
However It's not cool.

I took the gif animation.
Please click the link below.

https://gyazo.com/06622369ad530b9dc9a4cb5ee90b71dc

```js
let flag = true;
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (flag) {
      startGrap.play();
      flag = false;
    } else {
      endGrap.play();
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  const startGrap = gsap
    .timeline()
    .addLabel("start")
    .to(property, 0.5, {
      direction: -8.0,
      ease: "power2.out",
    })
    .to(property, 0.7, {
      direction: 0.0,
      ease: "back.out(3.0)",
    })
    .to(
      property,
      0.8,
      {
        offsetZ: 0.0,
        ease: "power3.inOut",
      },
      "start"
    )
    .pause();

  const endGrap = gsap
    .timeline()
    .addLabel("start")
    .to(property, 0.4, {
      direction: -8.0,
      ease: "power2.out",
    })
    .to(property, 0.4, {
      direction: 0.0,
      ease: "back.out(4)",
    })
    .to(
      property,
      0.8,
      {
        offsetZ: -500.0,
        ease: "power3.inOut",
      },
      "start"
    )
    .pause();
```

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because you don't include enough code to recreate the issue. With that being said, in cases like this you should *create the animation beforehand* and use control methods to control the animation inside of the event listeners as [this article talks about](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/#tip-9-use-control-methods). We at GreenSock also highly recommend that you [upgrade to GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3-migration/). It's better in every way!

Answer (score 0):

maybe I resolved how to way.
I make instance of timelinelite every time.

but I don't think this way is better.

https://gyazo.com/f9feaa276fa5e8a4b047d60adc39d610

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (flag) {
      new TimelineLite()
        .addLabel("start")
        .to(property, 0.5, {
          direction: -8.0,
          ease: "power2.out",
        })
        .to(property, 0.7, {
          direction: 0.0,
          ease: "back.out(3.0)",
        })
        .to(
          property,
          0.8,
          {
            offsetZ: 0.0,
            ease: "power3.inOut",
          },
          "start"
        );
    } else {
      new TimelineLite()
        .addLabel("start")
        .to(property, 0.4, {
          direction: -8.0,
          ease: "power2.out",
        })
        .to(property, 0.4, {
          direction: 0.0,
          ease: "back.out(4)",
        })
        .to(
          property,
          0.8,
          {
            offsetZ: -500.0,
            ease: "power3.inOut",
          },
          "start"
        );
    }
    flag = !flag;
  });
```